# Inyectar codigo javascript en adobe target

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando inyectar el código de javascript en el custome code de adobe target pero no funciona.  Cuando pongo mi código en la consola se agrega el nuevo apartado que he creado perfectamente pero no en A.T.

Usamos SPA por lo que necesitaría descargar at.js pero por los momentos no podemos descargar y usar la nueva versión.

Me dijeron que puedo usar un "form based" pero debo estar haciendo algo mal porque no funciona.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si compartes lo que has intentado hasta el momento tu pregunta quedara mucho mejor!

Comment: Gracias, voy a añadir info extra